# How to enumerate data returned from Observable Subscription in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-services, angularjs-components

I've the basic idea about how observable works, I'm able to get the data by calling subscribe method and render the data in my template. But I could not enumerate the data returned by the observable in my component. I would like to process my data at component level before sending them to my template.

I've tried this so far:

My Service:

```
getCountries(): Observable<IUser> {
   return this.http.get<IUser>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
}
```

My ngInit method in the component:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.countryService.getCountries().subscribe((users => {
       this.userJson = users;
    }));

    console.log(this.userJson); // Showing undefined

    //giving exception while calling length property
    for (var i = 0; i < this.userJson.length; i++) {
    }
}
```

Not sure how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the console.log inside the subscribe to make it work, why do you need to call inside? because its an asynchronous request;You can loop over the items by calling a function as follows,

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.countryService.getCountries().subscribe((users => {
    this.userJson = users;
    console.log(this.userJson); 
    printMe(this.usersJson);
}));

printMe : void (){
  for (var i = 0; i < this.userJson.length; i++) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your logic inside `subscribe` method. It is an asynchronous call and you can't know when it will be finished.

```
this.countryService.getCountries().subscribe((users => {
   this.userJson = users;

   console.log(this.userJson);

   for (var i = 0; i < this.userJson.length; i++) {

   }
}));
```

You can still work with `userJson` in the markup - Angular will detect when the value of the `this.userJson` will be updated and it will update UI automatically.

Comment: Thanks! That was fast...! :)